# How to display an Excel array without excel #N/As using C# Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I have a c# function returning a matrix, I read it on Excel (as an excel array). Anyone has an idea how to:

1)Display/expand the full array without having to use ctrl+shift+enter and readjust to remove #N/As.

2) expand only in empty Excel cells i.e do not overwrite existing cells.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the new 'Dynamic Arrays' being tested in the insider versions of Excel. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Preview-of-Dynamic-Arrays-in-Excel/ba-p/252944 and other Google hits when you search for 'Excel dynamic array'.

Comment: That sounds interesting but only works with Microsoft defined functions and not yet available.

Comment: No - it works for user-defined functions that return arrays too!

Comment: Else you can try the old Excel-DNA "ArrayResizer" sample: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna